# Add data/model instance to M2M field dynamically when creating model with dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a model with `m2m` field using a dictionary.
Something like:

```
data = {fieldA: "hello", fieldB: "world", m2m: [ModelInstance, ]}    
model_instance.objects.create(**data)
```

I tried adding the m2m value I'm trying to set in an array but I keep getting the exception

```
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the m2m-data after you've created the instance, like so:

```py
data = {fieldA: "hello", fieldB: "world", m2m: [ModelInstance, ]}
m2m_data = data.pop("m2m")  # remove the key from the dict

instance = model_instance.objects.create(**data)
instance.m2m.add(m2m_data)
```